# Python - Tkinter - Using after method and cotroll for framerate

Tags: python, tkinter, frame-rate

is it possible to use the .after()-method with fps instead of defining the milliseconds. So I want a Label depicted for 6 Frames (60 Hz). 
--> root.after(6) instead of defining the time in ms.

For example:

```
root = tk.Tk()

ListofStimuli = ["\u00B6","\u0126"]

labelprint = tk.Label(root,text="+", font = ('Sans','80','bold'), bg = "white")
labelprint.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")


for elem in ListofStimuli:

    labelprint.config(text=elem) 
    root.after(100, lambda: var.set(0))
    root.wait_variable(var)
```

Comment: If you want 60 frames per second, just divide 1000 milliseconds (1 second) by 60. That will tell you how many milliseconds equates to 60fps.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I was inaccurate. I have a screen with a refreshrate of 60 Hz. In my understanding the screen will update every 16,67ms and deliver a new picture. I want my program to display the element for exactly 6 frames (6 * 16,67ms). So I believe if I do not control for the exact stimulus display time, it is possible that an element will be depicted for 7 or 5 frames. Is it possible to adapt the after-method for slight differences to allow for millisecond priming?

Comment: `after` is never guaranteed to be accurate. The only guarantee it offers is that the function will not be called before the time elapses. If you set it to 16ms, it could run in 16ms, or it could be 17 or 18 or 100 or 1000, depending on what else is happening in your program and on your system. That being said, you can do whatever math you want to try to accommodate for variances.

Comment: Obviously I am not a programer. But I want to do it most exactly for a psychological research. Are there any ideas how I can fulfill the requiered specifications?

Answer (score 2):

> That being said, you can do whatever math you want to try to
>   accommodate for variances. – Bryan Oakley

along this line of thought, keep list of elapsed times of your loop; then subtract average refresh from your preferred UI refresh rate.  Iteratively move towards preferred refresh rate on nano scale to account for timing irregularities.

This will achieve and maintain 1ms precision within about 1 second, which is as precise as the after() method will allow, given input is integers of milleseconds.  The method will work for any tick size down to millesecond.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

UI_REFRESH = 100 # your preferred refresh rate in milleseconds
UI_DELTA = 0.000001 # nanosecond scale iterative filter step size
UI_DEPTH = 10 # depth of ui_refreshes moving average

def animate():

    global last_refresh, ui_refreshes, last_refresh, ui_delta

    print("\033c") # clear terminal    
    # keep moving average of UI_REFRESH timing
    now = time.time()
    ui_refreshes.append(now - last_refresh)
    ui_refreshes = ui_refreshes[-UI_DEPTH:]
    ui_refresh = sum(ui_refreshes) / len(ui_refreshes)
    last_refresh = now

    # filter nanosecond scale timing oddities iteratively
    # both as they arise due to load and between various systems
    refresh_error = abs(UI_REFRESH_SEC-ui_refresh)
    if float('%.5f' % ui_refresh) < (UI_REFRESH_SEC):
        ui_delta += UI_DELTA
    if float('%.5f' % ui_refresh) > (UI_REFRESH_SEC):
        ui_delta -= UI_DELTA

    # do whatever your loop does
    # note this must take less time than your refresh rate!!
    print(  int(time.time()),
            ('%.6f' % ui_refresh),
            ('%.6f' % refresh_error),
            ('%.4f' % round(ui_refresh, 4)),
            int(1000*round(ui_refresh, 4)))

    # set perfect UI_REFRESH timing
    pause = int(1000 *
                min(UI_REFRESH_SEC, (
                    max(0, (
                        2 * UI_REFRESH_SEC - ui_refresh + ui_delta)))))
    master.after(pause, animate)

print("\033c") # clear terminal
UI_REFRESH_SEC = UI_REFRESH/1000
ui_refreshes = []
last_refresh = time.time()
ui_delta = 0
master = tk.Tk()
master.after(0, animate)
master.mainloop()
```